# Having a problem in webhook connection in express for a shopify app

Tags: express, shopify, webhooks

I want to send my orders to a print company(3rd party). for that I created one app.
I added this code in express,

```
router.post('/webhooks/orders/create', (req, res) => {
  console.log(' We got an order!');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I created webhook in admin side in Shopify

[image]

Now, when I click on send test notification, I am getting this

> POST /webhooks/orders/create 404 155.897 ms - 3196

I referred this link https://medium.com/@scottdixon/verifying-shopify-webhooks-with-nodejs-express-ac7845c9e40a

Comment: Sorry, not getting the issue, webhook seems to be working and the log is present in your node server.